# Importing fixed delimited file into Pandas with datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read a fixed width file into Pandas using the read.fwf() function for the following data below with the following fixed widths. Can anyone help me fix my code to get this loaded with the correct data types. Thanks!

Sample Data:

```
0000   51243 603896 1 EPS 1412    0.5100 140408 08:55:38 140408 08:55:38 X 140414 10:28:23
0000   51243 603896 1 EPS 1412    0.5700 140716 15:35:07 140716 15:35:07 X 240713 15:35:07
AACC   00371 071417 1 EPS 0912    0.2900 090821 18:28:01 091116 21:46:13 X 191117 21:49:53
AACC   51308 571315 1 EPS 0912    0.1100 091105 18:11:49 091105 18:10:24 X 191103 18:10:24
AACE   00505 048634 1 EPS 0006    0.9900 000607 17:24:39 000613 12:26:11 X                
AAGD   51020 537668 1 EPS 1212   20.2000 120810 02:58:09 120814 14:48:50 X 220812 14:48:50
AAGD   51020 537668 1 EPS 1212   20.4000 120830 07:32:29 120830 07:30:49 X 220828 07:30:49
```

[Field Definitions + Length + Datatype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QMdX.png)

Comment: Can you explain the problem that you have with the function `pd.read_fwf()`?

Comment: If I use the following code below, The time fields, aren't lining up. There is 1 extra space after each field so I think that is the issue and also defining the data types. 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('File.txt', widths=[6,5,6,1,3,4,9,6,8,6,8,1,6,8], names = ['TICKER','ESTIMATOR', 'ANALYST_CODE', 'Forecast_Period', 'Measure', 'Period_End_Date', 'Value', 'Activation_Date', 'Activation_Time', 'Exclude_Date', 'Exclude_time', 'Exclude_Flag', 'Exclude_end_Date', 'Exclude_end_time'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the `colspecs` instead. The issue with your code is that you are not accounting for the spaces in between when you provide the width:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('test.csv',
                 colspecs=[
                     (0, 6),
                     (7, 12),
                     (13, 19),
                     (20, 21),
                     (22, 25),
                     (26, 30),
                     (31, 40),
                     (41, 47),
                     (48, 56),
                     (57, 63),
                     (64, 72),
                     (73, 74),
                     (75, 81),
                     (82, 90),
                 ],
                 names=['TICKER', 'ESTIMATOR', 'ANALYST_CODE', 'Forecast_Period', 'Measure', 'Period_End_Date', 'Value',
                        'Activation_Date', 'Activation_Time', 'Exclude_Date', 'Exclude_time', 'Exclude_Flag',
                        'Exclude_end_Date', 'Exclude_end_time'])
print(df)


 TICKER  ESTIMATOR  ANALYST_CODE  Forecast_Period Measure  Period_End_Date  Value  Activation_Date Activation_Time  Exclude_Date Exclude_time Exclude_Flag  Exclude_end_Date Exclude_end_time
0   0000        NaN           NaN              NaN    None              NaN    NaN              NaN            None           NaN         None         None               NaN             None
1   0000    51243.0      603896.0              1.0     EPS           1412.0   0.57         140716.0        15:35:07      140716.0     15:35:07            X          240713.0         15:35:07
2   AACC      371.0       71417.0              1.0     EPS            912.0   0.29          90821.0        18:28:01       91116.0     21:46:13            X          191117.0         21:49:53
3   AACC    51308.0      571315.0              1.0     EPS            912.0   0.11          91105.0        18:11:49       91105.0     18:10:24            X          191103.0         18:10:24
4   AACE      505.0       48634.0              1.0     EPS              6.0   0.99            607.0        17:24:39         613.0     12:26:11            X               NaN              NaN
5   AAGD    51020.0      537668.0              1.0     EPS           1212.0  20.20         120810.0        02:58:09      120814.0     14:48:50            X          220812.0         14:48:50
6   AAGD    51020.0      537668.0              1.0     EPS           1212.0  20.40         120830.0        07:32:29      120830.0     07:30:49            X          220828.0         07:30:49
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks like the last column isn't loading properly. It is returning NaN instead of the time. Any ideas why?

Comment: Check edited answer. Missed (13, 19) in the colspec

Comment: That did it! For Dates is there a way to put it in as an INT or something without the .0 at the end?

Comment: You can always change to int later.

Comment: Thanks for your help!